# Matrix multipication is very slow C++

Tags: c++, matrix, exponential

I dont know why but my matrix multipication is very slow and I need to optimize it. and also the print of the matrix (1000X1000) taking long time.
The aim of the function is to calculate the matrix exponential, but my main problem is that this 2 actions are very slow for large matrices like 1000X1000.

These 2 actions implemented at poweMat() function and printeResult() function.
Here is the code:

```
    #define M 1000
    #define e 2.71828182845904523536;
    
    //declaration of the functions
    void sumMatrices(vector<vector<double> >& mat1, vector<vector<double> >& mat2);
    void printResult(vector<vector<double> >&matRes);
    void mulMatWithFactorial(long factorialValue);
    long factorialCalculate(int n);
    void initializeMatrix();
    void initializeIdenticalMatrix();
    void checkIfTheMatrixIsDiagonal();
    void calculateExpoMatrixWithDiagonalMatrix();
    void readMatrixFromFile();
    void powerMat(vector<vector<double> >& mat, int powNum);
    
    //declaration of the variables
    vector<vector<double>> inputMatrix(M, vector<double>(M));
    vector<vector<double>> sumMatrixResult(M, vector<double>(M));
    vector<vector<double>> powerMatrixResult(M, vector<double>(M));
    vector<vector<double>> mulFactorialMatrixResult(M, vector<double>(M));
    vector<vector<double>> finalMatrixResult(M, vector<double>(M));
    vector<vector<double>> identicalMatrix(M, vector<double>(M));
    vector<vector<vector<double>>> listOfMatrices;
    bool matrixIsNilpotent = false;
    int diagonaMatrixlFlag = 1;
    
    int main() {
        //variables
        long factorialValue;
        
    initializeIdenticalMatrix();
    readMatrixFromFile();

    //check if the matrix is diagonal - so we will have easier and faster compute
    checkIfTheMatrixIsDiagonal();
    if (diagonaMatrixlFlag == 1) {
        calculateExpoMatrixWithDiagonalMatrix();
        goto endOfLoop;
    }
    
    //loop for taylor series
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (i == 0) { // first we add identical matrix when the power is 0
            sumMatrices(finalMatrixResult, identicalMatrix); // summarize between this 2 matrices
            finalMatrixResult = sumMatrixResult; //copy matrices
        }
        
        if (i == 1) { // we add the matrix itself because the power is 1
            sumMatrices(finalMatrixResult, inputMatrix);
            finalMatrixResult = sumMatrixResult; //copy matrices
        }
        if (i > 1 ) {
            powerMat(inputMatrix, i);
            if (matrixIsNilpotent) { // it means that A^i is 0 for some integer, so the series terminates after a finite number
                goto endOfLoop;
            }
            factorialValue = factorialCalculate(i); // calculate the factorial of i
            mulMatWithFactorial(factorialValue); // multiply (1/i) * matrix^i - like in the algorithm
            sumMatrices(finalMatrixResult, mulFactorialMatrixResult); // summarize it with the previous result
            finalMatrixResult = sumMatrixResult; //copy matrices
        }
    }
    
    endOfLoop:
    printResult(finalMatrixResult); // print the final result - e^M
    return 0;
}
    
//Summarize matrices
void sumMatrices(vector<vector<double> >& mat1, vector<vector<double> >& mat2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            sumMatrixResult[i][j] = mat1[i][j] + mat2[i][j];
}

//Print matrix
void printResult(vector<vector<double> >& matRes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            printf("%f ", matRes[i][j]);
            if (j == M - 1) {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}


//Calculate the factorial of n
long factorialCalculate(int n) {
    long factorial = 1.0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        factorial *= i;
    }
    return factorial;
}

// mutiply the matrix with scalar
void mulMatWithFactorial(long factorialValue) {
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            mulFactorialMatrixResult[i][j] = powerMatrixResult[i][j] * 1/factorialValue;
        }
    }
}

//initialize matrix
void initializeMatrix() {
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            powerMatrixResult[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void checkIfTheMatrixIsDiagonal() {
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            if (i == j)
            {
                if (inputMatrix[i][j] == 0) {
                    diagonaMatrixlFlag = 0;
                    goto endOfLoop;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if (inputMatrix[i][j] != 0) {
                    diagonaMatrixlFlag = 0;
                    goto endOfLoop;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    endOfLoop:
    return;
}

void calculateExpoMatrixWithDiagonalMatrix() {
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            if (i == j)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < inputMatrix[i][j]; ++k)// loop to calculate the pow of e^alpha
                {
                    finalMatrixResult[i][j] *= e;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                finalMatrixResult[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

void readMatrixFromFile() {
    ifstream f("inv_matrix(1000x1000).txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            f >> inputMatrix[i][j];
            if (f.peek() == ',')
                f.ignore();
        }
    listOfMatrices.push_back(inputMatrix);
}

void initializeIdenticalMatrix() {
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < M; k++) {
            if (i == k) {
                identicalMatrix[i][k] = 1;
            }
            else {
                identicalMatrix[i][k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

void powerMat(vector<vector<double> >& mat, int powNum) {
    int counterForNilpotent = 0;

    initializeMatrix();
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < M; k++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
                powerMatrixResult[i][j] += mat[i][k] * listOfMatrices[powNum-2][k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<seconds>(stop - start);
    cout << duration.count() << " seconds" << endl; // checking run time

    listOfMatrices.push_back(powerMatrixResult);

    // check if after we we did A^i , the matrix is equal to 0
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            if (powerMatrixResult[i][j] == 0) {
                counterForNilpotent++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (counterForNilpotent == M * M) {
        matrixIsNilpotent = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Representing a matrix as a vector of vectors is very inefficient. Instead, use a single vector only and store elements in some defined order (row-wise, column-wise, Z-order,...). Anyway, much better would be to use some library, such as an implementation of BLAS optimized for your system. Additionally, you also want to employ threading if you are on a multi-core system (which is likely).

Comment: I cant use libraries due to restrictions

Comment: Are you timing a release / optimized build? In Visual Studio I have seen cases where a debug build took 100 times as look to run as release with the same data  and code.

Comment: @daniel Can you use multithreading? With matrix-vector operations, you can generally get almost perfect speedup.

Comment: Experience tells me that most "X is too slow"-questions are caused, because people are timing debug builds or have inacurate methods of meassurement. So, did you already try to build in release-configuration? And how do you meassure the time?

Comment: There is more room for improvement. For example, you explicitly store the identity matrix and then add it to other matrices. Much faster would be just to add ones to their diagonal.

Comment: Locality is a big problem here. Unless theses are sparse matrices don't use vector of vector.  Use 1 flat vector and write the few lines of code to 2D index into it.  Organise the matrix multiplication such that memory is traversed in physical address order as much as possible.  And probably before you start profile the program to ensure you know where the hotspots really are.

Comment: what is the meaning of release / optimized build? I run the code with ctrl + F5.

Comment: If I took your code, generated random data, and ran it with optimizations turned on, the matrix multiplication takes a second or less.  [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/M5Tevodfs).

Comment: And there is option to create list of 2D arrays if I will save them as flat array ?

Comment: @daniel -- No.  Go to your project settings or whatever, and change the configuration to release, not debug.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so what is the problem? how i run it with optimizations?

Comment: @daniel -- If you are using Visual Studio, what do you see above the main menu for the configuration?  Do you see `Debug`?  If you do, change it to `Release`.  Also *the print of the matrix (1000X1000) taking long time* -- There is nothing you can do about that -- you cannot control the speed of the console.  In any event, it shouldn't matter, as what counts is the raw calculations, not how you want to display them.

Comment: @churill -- I bet this will be yet another "oops, I forgot to time an optimized build -- never mind" sort of a question.  About to close as a typo if this turns out to be true.

Comment: oh my god its working! so this is the default way that i should run programs? and what is the difference between them ?

Comment: The debug mode is built for that -- when you are debugging your program.  The release mode is for when your program is working, and you want the compiler's optimizer to optimize the code (remove variables, inline functions, etc. etc.).  The debug mode is there because you *don't* want the compiler to change (too much) your original source code, so that it is easier to debug.  Since the release mode can make drastic changes to the final program produced, you don't really want to try and debug a release build, given that the code will not match up with the source code.

Comment: ok thanks. but I can see that the print is still slow. there is nothing to do with that? It printin 1000x1000 matrix.

Comment: Reminder:  pass the vector by reference so that the compiler does not make a copy.  Making unnecessary copies slows down program execution.

Comment: @daniel Slow console output is a common problem on windows iirc.

Answer (score 0):

Going through each element of an array of size "n" will have some computational efficiency of O(n^2), meaning for large arrays it will take a while but won't be "life-time-of-the-universe" lengths of time.

Usually to do operations on massive arrays like this, they're reduced in some form first so that the computation can be closer to O(n) or better using some truths about reduced forms of matrices.

**So, a faster implementation for matrix multiplication would start with some rref() function upon both matrices and then only evaluating parts of those matrices that would have objects in the columns and rows.**

Here are some great places to review/learn (for free) Linear Algebra:

"3b1b (2016): Essence of Linear Algebra" = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjBOesZCoqc&list=PL0-GT3co4r2y2YErbmuJw2L5tW4Ew2O5B

"MIT OpenCourseWare (2009): Linear Algebra" = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZK3O402wf1c&list=PL49CF3715CB9EF31D&index=1

Answer (score -2):

Use SSE2.  It’s not a library.  It’s a method to use cpu vector hardware.

You set up operations to run in parallel.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2

Comment: Compilers are able to generate SIMD instructions for you if the code and the program logic is good. Generally, only highly experienced programmers would outperform compiler-generated machine code in this regard.

Comment: BTW, why SSE2? Why not AVX, or AVX2? We even don't know the target platform, what if it is ARM?

Comment: [What has my compiler done for me lately, Matt Godbolt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4). And if you want vectorization you can also use `std::foreach` with [std::unsequenced_policy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag)